# Sync ROR Calendar to Google Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I have a ROR APP that has GEM "simple calendar" installed.

is there a way to sync that calendar with Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same feature to implement with ruby. I done this with `gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.11'` and `gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"`. I am sharing my repo link I prepared as demo. Hope It will help you.
https://github.com/RaviSys/Cal-Event/